# What does "You do not have necessary license to run tool" mean when ArcGIS extension installed and activated?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, spatial-analyst, license, arcgis-personal-use

I just purchased **[ArcGIS for Home Use 10.2](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgis-for-home)** and installed and activated the extensions with the codes I received from Esri. The ArcGIS Administrator says Yes for Installed and Authorized, and even has an expiration date.

However, when I try to run the tool it states "You do not have the necessary license to run the tool" and that there is no license available or installed.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: You need to enable each extension in ArcMap http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018900000002000000

Comment: That seemed to work, that was incredibly ridiculous of me not to figure out. It was spatial analyst though.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @Mapperz:

> You need to enable each extension in ArcMap

This is documented in the Help under [Using Extensions in ArcGIS](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018900000002000000).